# Restore MySQL databases from /var/mysql directory

Tags: mysql

I'm using MySQL 5.1.38 on a clean install of OS X 10.6, where the databases are stored in /usr/local/mysql/data. I have a backup of my old mysql data directory, but the databases were stored in /var/mysql/dbname.

Is there any way I can get my databases back?

Answer (score 2):

If MySQL was shutdown cleanly, you should be able to move the files that had been in /var/mysql/dbname into /usr/local/mysql/data while mysql is stopped, and then start mysql and have it pick them up.